# Forth function like structures

Tags: forth, gforth

I am playing around with Forth, and I am trying to see if it has a function-like structure. I am trying to understand it coming from an OOP background.

I have seen you can have something like:

```
: addition + . ;
4 2 addition 6 ok
```

Is there a way to have it so you could have variables like:

```
: addition ( a b )
a b + ;
4 2 addition . 6 ok
```

So that I could do more complex things with that word definition.

Comment: A word definition *is* a function-like structure. Are you trying to ask how to refer to the arguments by name? That's not how it works; they are just objects on the stack which the caller hopefully put there in the order required by the word definition.

Comment: Of course you *could* use (essentially global) variables but this is considered bad practice. https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/8-variables-constants-arrays/

Comment: Gforth supports local variables: https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Local-Variables-Tutorial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional syntax for local variables uses `{` and `}`.  Your examples would become:

```
: addition { a b -- } a b + ;
```

The standard uses `{:` and `:}` instead.

http://forth-standard.org/standard/locals/bColon